# how to make the following plot?

Tags: r

How do I make the following plot in R?

I have a file of the format:

```
0 2 5 911.2
0 4 10 842.59
1 6 15 813.23
1 8 20 823.23
1 2 15 813.31
0 4 5 844.59
0 6 25 854.54
```

The first column can be 0 or 1 only. The second column can be 2, 4, 6, 8 or 1. The third column is an integer. The fourth column is a double.

I want to create a plot such that that the X axis is the third column, the Y axis is the fourth column, the color designates the number in the second column (with maybe going from green to red in a cold-hot color scheme) and the shape (let's say triangle versus circle) tells whether the first column is 1 or 0. I would also like a legend for all of this (the color and the shape of the points).

Any ideas?

I know how to create the matrix, so you can assume that I have a file loaded as a matrix there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a go.

```
## Run only the first time
install.packages("ggplot2")

## Change to data.frame
mydf <- as.data.frame(yourMatrix)
names(mydf) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")
require(ggplot2)
qplot(x = c3, y = c4, color = c2, shape = as.factor(c1), data = mydf)
```